# Accessing Variables from other Public Classes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-c#-express-2010

I've seen 3-4 questions on this that were answered already on stackoverflow, and they said to do what I've been doing. I'm not to sure why this isn't working, but basically I'm trying to put all of my variables in 'vars.cs', and be able to access them in 'Form1.cs'. Here's the code in the vars.cs file:

```
public static class vars
{
    public static string charName;
}
```

And here's what I'm doing in Form1.cs, trying to access it:

```
    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        charName = textBox1.Text;
        MessageBox.Show(charName);
    }
```

I've also tried using different classes within the same file, and I still can't access variables across classes.

Thanks, Nash.

P.S. The error it's giving me is "The name 'charName' does not exist in the current context'

Comment: If you will explore little you will have answer. Its very basic.

Comment: I did do some looking around, but I think my problem was so simple and basic that no one really took the time to point it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to access it with the full name

```
[Namespace].[Class].[VariableName]
```

where namespace is optional if you having it in a using statement, leaving you with:

```
vars.charName
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the class that is holding all of your variables is marked as `static`, you need to reference those variables through the class name, `vars.charName`.  If it wasn't a static class then you'd have to define an instance of it first and then reference the variables through that instance:

```
vars myVars = new vars();
MessageBox.Show(myVars.charName);
```